# iOS Audio Files not playing

Tags: ios, audio

I am trying to play my audio file, which is 1.9 seconds, in my iOS App with these lines of code:

```
NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bell" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath : path];
SystemSoundID audioEffect;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(audioEffect);
```

The audio file never plays but the code gets called.

[image: file]

**EDIT:** `file bell.wav
bell.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, stereo 48000 Hz`

Comment: 1. Check if pathURL is not NULL (add an NSLog). 2. Check if the WAV file actually is plain PCM (not some strange ADPCM or MP3 etc.) - when in doubt, convert it to plain 16bit PCM.

Comment: @Till The path is not nil

Comment: Did you check point 2? Please give us all details from a run of `file bell.wav` in the terminal.

Comment: Your audio encoding looks fine. Any iOS device should play that stuff just fine. Well then, try a different sound, make sure your device is not muted when testing and if everything fails, try a different API (e.g. AVFramework).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are disposing the sound before it has a chance to start playing.

My book teaches you how to do this. Here is the code I provide in my book:

```
void SoundFinished (SystemSoundID snd, void* context) {
    // NSLog(@"finished!");
    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(snd);
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(snd);
}

- (IBAction)doButton:(id)sender {
    NSURL* sndurl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"aif"];
    SystemSoundID snd;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)sndurl, &snd);
    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(snd, nil, nil, SoundFinished, nil);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(snd);
}
```

You can adapt that to use your sound and to trigger the playing in the way you need.

However, do note that you should not be using a 1.9 second sound as a system sound. It is much better to use an AVAudioPlayer (which my book also teaches you to do).